# how to insert file into JAR using PHP

Tags: javascript, java, php, jar

I want to build a program for insert into jar. The jar path like this.

```
File.jar\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

Is it possible to insert file into **folder3** if i using PHP? or maybe i have to use another?

If it is possible, how the code for it?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to roll it up really tight, and then push really hard.  Once you get it in the Jar put the lid back on super tight.  PHP files can be really elastic.

Comment: Why not to write Shell or batch script to unpack and repack jar using `java`?

Comment: @Ivan there is so many files in our jar. if i unpack and repack jar again, i think it will take a long time.

Comment: A jar file is just a zip file. So just add the file to the jar using some zip methods. [First result for "php add file to zip"](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php). Might be what you need.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks johannes. So can i add into specified path in jar? like an example : File.jar\folder1\folder2\folder3. I add into folder3